# How to configure OpenLiberty 18.0.0.2 to use Liberty embedded messaging?

Tags: java, jms, websphere-liberty, open-liberty, java-ee-8

I am trying to configure the OpenLiberty 18.0.0.2 to use embedded messaging for sending some simple JMS messages.

My current `server.xml` looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<server description="new server">
  <featureManager>
    <feature>javaee-8.0</feature>
    <feature>mpConfig-1.2</feature>
    <feature>mpMetrics-1.1</feature>
    <feature>wasJmsServer-1.0</feature>
    <feature>wasJmsClient-2.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
  </featureManager>
  <quickStartSecurity userName="admin" userPassword="adminpwd" />

  <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" />

  <applicationManager autoExpand="true" />
  <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean" />

  <messagingEngine>
    <queue id="QUEUE1" />
  </messagingEngine>

  <jmsQueueConnectionFactory jndiName="jms/JmsFactory">
    <properties.wasJms remoteServerAddress="localhost:7276:BootStrapBasicMessaging" />
  </jmsQueueConnectionFactory>

  <jmsQueue jndiName="jms/JmsQueue">
    <properties.wasJms queueName="QUEUE1" />
  </jmsQueue>
</server>
```

And my JMS sender looks like the following:

```
public class JmsMessageSender {


    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/JmsFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory jmsFactory;

    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/JmsQueue")
    private Queue jmsQueue;

    public void send() {

        TextMessage message;

        try (Connection connection = jmsFactory.createConnection();
             Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
             MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(jmsQueue)) {

            message = session.createTextMessage();
            message.setText("Hello World!");
            producer.send(message);

        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I am running my application I get the following exception when I am trying to send the message to the embedded messaging queue:

```
javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: CWSIA0281E: The specified value null is not allowed for Destination.
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsDestinationImpl.checkNativeInstance(JmsDestinationImpl.java:993)
[err]   at [internal classes]
```

It looks like my code can't obtain the queue destination through `JNDI`. Did I configure embedded messaging incorrectly or is the error in my source code?

**UPDATE 1**:

I updated the source code so that I won't pass the destination to the `.send()` method an now I am getting the following error on startup:

```
[ERROR   ] cdi.resource.injection.error.CWOWB1000E                                                                                                           
CWNEN0030E: The server was unable to obtain an object instance for the java:comp/env/de.rieckpil.blog.JmsMessageSender/jmsQueue reference.  
The exception message was: CWNEN1004E: The server was unable to find the de.rieckpil.blog.JmsMessageSender/jmsQueue default binding with the javax.jms.Queue type for the java:comp/env/de.rieckpil.blog.JmsMessageSender/jmsQueue reference.
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Sending the message now works, but I am unable to receive the message. My message driven bean looks like the following (the feature `mdb-3.2` is enabled):

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination",
                propertyValue = "jms/JmsQueue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType",
                propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
})
public class JmsMessageReader implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
        try {
            System.out.println("Message arrived: " + textMessage.getText());
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Update after comment that there was an issue with resource injection

First, fix the JMS API usage to only pass in the destination once (not on both `createProducer()` and `send()`.  Otherwise you may experience a **CWSIA0066E** failure.

Second, change the `@Resource` attributed from **mappedName** to **lookup**

### These changes are reflected below:

```
@Resource(lookup = "jms/JmsFactory")
private ConnectionFactory jmsFactory;

@Resource(lookup = "jms/JmsQueue")
private Queue jmsQueue;

public void send() {

    TextMessage message;

    try (Connection connection = jmsFactory.createConnection();
         Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
         MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(jmsQueue)) {

        message = session.createTextMessage();
        message.setText("Hello World!");

        // Don't pass in destination again since you set it in createProducer()
        producer.send(message);   

        // ...
```

### `@Resource` injection

Finally, `@Resource` injection isn't going to work in any old POJO, but only in special classes that are scanned by the container.   Try moving the injection to a servlet, EJB, or CDI managed bean.

### Terminology note:

Though I can see why you would have thought to call this "embedded MQ", the "messaging engine" you're using here is provided by what is actually called [Liberty embedded messaging](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cwlp_msg_embedded.html).

It is also a JMS provider.  That is, it implements the JMS API, as does MQ, the other IBM-provided JMS provider that can be used in Liberty.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated the codebase in the question and tried your modification. Now I am getting a different error: `CWOWB1000E`

Comment: OK, I reorganized the response since you're maybe having an issue with injection.

Comment: thank you, now my JMS sender works. Now I have troubles with receiving the message within a message driven bean. My server has the feature `mdb-3.2` enabled but I don't receive any data. I updated the question for the simple message driven bean

Comment: I understand this is one sample effort on your part, but the MDB part seems better suited for breaking out into a separate question.

Comment: You probably need to configure an activationSpec for the MDB

Comment: Okay, thanks for your support. I'll try the activationSpec and open a new question if I need help :D